# Unwanted rows in data.frame

Tags: r

I want to write a function that checks a certain number of files name *id*.csv and that will return the number of rows with no `NA`s.
Here is what I wrote:

```
        complete <- function(directory, id) {
        setwd(directory)
        my_list <- list.files(getwd(), pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
        my_id <- numeric()
        my_output<-data.frame()
        my_count<-numeric()
        for(integer in id){
            my_data <- read.csv(my_list[integer])
            my_subset <- subset(my_data, sulfate !=0 & nitrate !=0)
            my_count[integer]<-length(my_subset[[1]])
            my_id[integer] <- integer
        }
        my_output<-cbind(my_id, my_count)
        my_output
    }
complete("/home/jpasquier/Téléchargements/specdata", c(1,3))
```

But here is the result:

```
> complete("/home/jpasquier/Téléchargements/specdata", c(1,3))
     my_id my_count
[1,]     1      117
[2,]    NA       NA
[3,]     3      243
```

So I don't understand why there is an unwanted row number2, after all there is no integer that equal 2 in my id argument.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, look into [complete.cases](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/complete.cases.html)

Comment: I don't see where you think you are counting the number of rows with no NAs. @zx8754 often it is necessary to reinvent the wheel in order to learn things

Comment: Agree on "learn things", the function is called `complete` which checks if 2 variables are not zeros...

Comment: to subset a data frame with rows where two variables are not zero is *not* the same as counting the number of rows with no NAs ............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `NA`s because you are assigning values to 1st and 3rd value of the variable, and nothing for the 2nd.

Example:

```
v <- vector()
v
#logical(0)
v[1] <- 111
v[3] <- 333

v
#[1] 111  NA 333
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a working example, no need to create a function:

```
#create dummy csv
df1 <- data.frame(x=c(1,NA,2,0,4, 4),
                  y=c(1,3, 4,0,NA,6))
df2 <- data.frame(x=c(1,0,2,0, 4,0),
                  y=c(1,0,4,0,NA,0))

write.csv(df1,"id_1.csv",row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(df1,"id_2.csv",row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(df2,"id_3.csv",row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(df2,"id_4.csv",row.names = FALSE)

#choose which CSV
id <- c(1,3)

#get non zero counts
res <- lapply(lapply(list.files(pattern="^id.*.csv")[id],read.csv),
              function(i)nrow(subset(i,x!=0,y!=0)))

#update result names
names(res) <- list.files(pattern="^id.*.csv")[id]

#output result counts
res
# $id_1.csv
# [1] 4
# 
# $id_3.csv
# [1] 3
```

Comment: thanks to @zx8754. I just added a new counter and now I have the expected behavior. Thanks.

<code>
complete <- function(directory, id) {
 setwd(directory)
 my_list <- list.files(getwd(), pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
 my_id <- numeric()
 my_output<-data.frame()
 my_count<-numeric()
 i<-1
 for(x in id){
  my_data <- read.csv(my_list[x])
  my_subset <- subset(my_data, sulfate !=0 & nitrate !=0)
  my_count[i]<-length(my_subset[[1]])
  my_id[i] <- x
  i<-i+1
 }
 my_output<-cbind(my_id, my_count)
 my_output
}

complete("/home/jpasquier/Téléchargements/specdata", c(1,2,3,5))
</code>